# Include additional Sources for recompile in gwtSuperDev Task

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gradle, gwt-super-dev-mode

I use the [GWT Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin). I have a second project which I included in my main project with:

```
dependencies {  
  compile(project(':core-project')) {
    transitive = false
  }
}
```

I have also created a `settings.gradle` which contains

```
includeFlat 'core-project'
```

The core-project is a library project. When I run `gradle gwtSuperDev` and change files in my main project recompile takes place but not if I change files in my core-project.

**How can I make that the core-project sources are also recompiled in SuperDevMode when they have changed?**

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your gradle dependencies are organized, you can simply add their source-files to the gwt section of your build.gradle file.

I have something like this in my build file:

```
gwt {
  gwtVersion = '2.7.0'
  if (System.getProperty('devmode') != null) {
    modules = ['dk.logiva.invoice.autoaccount.gwt.AutoAccountAdminDev']
    compiler {
        style = 'PRETTY';
        strict = true;
    }
    // include sources from inherited module
    src += project(':invoice:gwt:gwt-common').files('src/main/java')
  } else {
    modules = ['dk.logiva.invoice.autoaccount.gwt.AutoAccountAdmin']
  }
  devWar = file("${buildDir}/war")
  maxHeapSize = "3G"
}
...
dependencies {
  compile project(':invoice:gwt:gwt-common')
  ...
}
```